# How can i get csrftoken in view?

Tags: python, django, csrf

Is there any way to get  csrftoken in View straightly?

I want to get the current csrftoken in view but will change sometimes so get it from Cookies is not a good idea.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this:

```
django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request)
```

or

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

Reference: 
[How can I embed django csrf token straight into HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289860/how-can-i-embed-django-csrf-token-straight-into-html)

Comment: In form you must add

'<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="' + get_token(request) + '"/>'