# How to access the csrf_token inside django view

Tags: python, django, django-csrf, csrf-token

I'm trying to access the csrf_token inside the django view function.

I have tried importing the csrf:

```
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
```

and using it like this

```
landingPageHtml = landingPageHtml.replace('csrf_token', csrf(request)['csrf_token'])
```

But I'm getting an error. second argument must be a str not lazy object.

How can I access the csrf token in a view?

```
@login_required
def viewLandingPage(request, slug):

    lp = getLandingPage(request, slug)

    landingPageHtml = getLandingPageFile(request, lp['file'])

    landingPageHtml = landingPageHtml.replace(
        '{{ lp.seo_title }}', lp['seo_title'])

    landingPageHtml = landingPageHtml.replace(
        '{{ lp.seo_description }}', lp['seo_description'])

    landingPageHtml = landingPageHtml.replace('csrf_token', 'csrf_token')

    return HttpResponse(landingPageHtml)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i get csrftoken in view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347512/how-can-i-get-csrftoken-in-view)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i get csrftoken in view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347512/how-can-i-get-csrftoken-in-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this to get csrf token

```py
django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request)
```

Reference: [How can i get csrftoken in view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347512/how-can-i-get-csrftoken-in-view)